# Domain-Driven-Design Entities and Value Objects

Tags: java, c#, domain-driven-design

Does every type modeled in DDD have to be either an entity or a value object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in DDD you can modelled the following types of objects:

> **Domain Event:** A domain object that defines an event. Where a domain event is something that happened that domain experts care about.
>
> **Service:** When an operation does not conceptually belong to any object. Following the natural contours of the problem, you can implement these operations in services.
>
> **Repository:** methods for retrieving domain objects should delegate to a specialized Repository object such that alternative storage implementations may be easily interchanged.
>
> **Factory:** methods for creating domain objects should delegate to a specialized Factory object such that alternative implementations may be easily interchanged.

Comment: Plus any other types of objects you like...

Comment: There's no such restriction. Although the tactical patterns involves these, you aren't limited in any way. The tactical patterns are just OO done right.

Comment: @plalx Of course there's no restriction. DDD is just another formalization, a set of rules and methods. Will you use the repository or query objects - it's up to you.